Python Django Form - issue with checkboxes in ModelMultipleChoiceField
I have this model
class ProjectMember(models.Model):
    member_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    member_uid = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    member_reviewer_uid = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    member_roles = models.ManyToManyField('ProjectRole', blank=False)
    member_discipline = models.ManyToManyField('ProjectDiscipline', blank=False)

class ProjectRole(models.Model):
    role_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role_name

this Form
class ProjectMemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectMember
        fields = (
            'member_name',
            'member_uid',
            'member_reviewer_uid',
            'member_roles'
        )

        # member_roles = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        member_roles = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset=ProjectRole.objects.all(),
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            required=True,
            # empty_label=None,  # Hide the empty label for the select multiple widget.
        )

        widgets = {
            'member_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'member_uid': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'member_reviewer_uid': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

I have tried also the commented lines of code.
I am still getting only this I would call it listbox instead of checkboxes:

My issue is that I would like to have it as checkbox instead of this list to crosscheck everything I want to be active.
EDIT: Note that I do not intent to save any data into database. This is going to act as configuration server and output is .xml file.

Plug in a CheckboxSelectMultiple widget [Django-doc] instead to work with the `ManyToManyField:
class ProjectMemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectMember
        fields = (
            'member_name',
            'member_uid',
            'member_reviewer_uid',
            'member_roles',
        )

        widgets = {
            'member_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'member_uid': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'member_reviewer_uid': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control'}
            ),
            'member_roles': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }
or define the field where it belongs: in the form class, not the Meta:
class ProjectMemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    member_roles = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=ProjectRole.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        required=True,
        # empty_label=None,  # Hide the empty label for the select multiple widget.
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ProjectMember
        fields = (
            'member_name',
            'member_uid',
            'member_reviewer_uid',
            'member_roles',
        )

        widgets = {
            'member_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'member_uid': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'member_reviewer_uid': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control'}
            ),
        }

Thanks! All it took was to just move it to upper class instead of meta. So silly mistake. Thanks!
